# Flask-Dance and TokenExpiredError

Tags: python, flask

How do you code around this error:
`oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.TokenExpiredError`

I spent a while trying to do a `try/except` block but no luck on this. The errors seems to happen when the session is stale, but for life of me I can't figure out how to refresh the session.

Here's the code that causes that:

```
@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if google.authorized:
        user_profile = json.loads(google.get("/userinfo/v2/me").content)

        new_user = User.load_by_id(user_profile['id'])
        if not new_user:
            User.create(user_profile)
        else:
            login_user(new_user)
            if current_user.is_authenticated:
                return render_template("index.html", menu=menu)

    return redirect(url_for('user.signin'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is an issue posted over at [singingwolfboy/flaskdance#35](https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-dance/issues/35)

Answer (score 0):

I posted a comment on the issue referenced from the accepted answer. For flask it works to examine the token in `flask.session` and delete it if expired in a `before_request` function. This forces the client to request a new access token. As long as the user remains logged in then new tokens are issued seamlessly, without further authentication requests.